# How I can get an array of locations in python to scale instances in geometry nodes?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

I've created a mesh of points at locations from an array in a python script, then used this to spawn instances in geometry nodes.

I also have an array of sizes which I would like to apply via the scale field input on the instance on points node, (the indices correspond to the vertex order of the mesh/original location array).

How can I convert this array of sizes to something I can plug into the geometry node field input?

***Update***
A script which outlines what I'm trying to do is here https://pastebin.com/0D1HTuPR
Method one is the target result, and method two is trying to achieve with geometry nodes.

Comment: while text descriptions might be enough, better are always screenshots of e.g. node setups, providing your python code and even better providing your blend file. People like me who want to try out their solutions but are to lazy to rebuild everything manually would appreciate that and are more willing to help if you do so. So this might be one of the reasons why nobody commented or answered your questions in 15 hours, and other questions are answered in 30 minutes who do this.

Comment: Ok, I've added a script which remakes it, it is a rather simple problem though.. maybe I'm missing something